# Change date format in list view EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a listview but when macro is launched, it changes date format
from "[h]:mm:ss" to General.

My code says this

```
    itmX.SubItems(4) = Range("F" & i).Value
    itmX.SubItems(5) = Range("G" & i).Value
    itmX.SubItems(6) = Range("H" & i).Value
    itmX.SubItems(7) = Range("I" & i).Value
```

Is there any way to fix it? In order to get format "[h]:mm:ss"?
Thank you very much

Comment: Ah I thought you were trying to write to cells from your listview control not load into the listview control. I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

try after you've replaced the `.value with .text`, it should look like this:

```
timX.SubItems(4) = Range("F" &  i).Text
```

times and dates are just masks for a number in excel today's date or a time value are just numbers with a format mask like below

```
26/01/16 = 42395
1:02:03 = 0,0430902777777778
```

With the `value` you're setting your subitems to the underlying value of the cell

### End of Edit

---

You could use the `numberformat` property

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "[H]:mm:ss"
```

Comment: I have tried it - but only shows     True or False. :(

Comment: Ou, I see it now. Thank you for explanation. Awsome! I have been struggling with other formats as well and this helps me in all of them! Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can apply this

```
myTimeString.Text = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
```

i.e output

> myTimeString will display 03/24/2014 12:49:23 PM

Check [this](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-format-date/)

Regards
Claudio

Comment: Unfortunatelly this show only True or False in my list view :(